# very simple amateur question. Build a table then do group_concat

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I am very new to SQL and don't have much intuition for all this.  I have lots of coding experience but nothing in databases.

I have two scriptthat work in isolation, but I don't know how to stitch them together to do this all at once.

The first script:

```
SELECT *
  FROM PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.BCAPPLICATIONQUOTES bq 
JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.PRODUCT p ON bq.ProductId = p.Id 
JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.BCAPPLICATIONQUOTEFEES F on F.ApplicationQuoteId = bq.Id 
LEFT JOIN PROD_ANALYTIC.SRC_MVC_AU_DBO.COVERAGESECTIONTYPE CST ON F.CoverageSectionTypeID = CST.SECTIONID
```

This produces a table (is that the right word?). Suppose I could save that table as 'appQuote'. I then want to run this script on it:

```
select ApplicationId, 
            group_concat(YEARLYPAYAMOUNT) allPremium,
            group_concat(SECTIONID) allSection,
            group_concat(SHORTNAME) allSectionName,
            from appQuote group by ApplicationId
```

For storage reasons I don't want to actually save the table from the first script, I just want to get the result from the first script and immediately apply the second script to it.

This is very basic, so any guidance and intuition would help.

Comment: Which database system are you using?... Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using the desired columns and expressions in place of `*` in your first query (and, obviously, tagging the `group by` on its tail).

Comment: @J.D. I am using SQL Server primarily, but I was using some MySQL commands through R.

Comment: @mustaccio can you please be more specific? If I replaces * with the entire second script (or SQL Server equivalent) what does that actually do? It's not even clear to me in what order SQL evaluates these things.

Comment: Studying standard SQL syntax will undoubtedly benefit you in the long run. We could certainly give you a fish, but don't you want to begin fishing yourself?

Answer (score -1):

You want to learn about `WITH`. You can combine the two queries by adding

`WITH appQuote as (<select statement from your first script>) <select statement from your second script>`. Whenever possible, especially with automated functions, specify the column names rather than using `select *`. Using * has a high chance of breaking if your table's columns are ever modified.